# How do I combine multiple sorting/filtering logic in Django in efficient way?

Tags: django

I am trying to make a site that supports searching/sorting/filtering at the same time.
I did it in the 'if/elif' logic and it works! But it doesn't seem to be so efficient (from perspective of copying the code many times and inability to change something fast).

As you can see in code examlpe below, I just specify these conditions for each possible case, such as: "with filter1, but without filter2 and filter3"; "with filter1 and filter2, but without filter3" and so on.

As you can imagine, adding filters 4 and 5 sounds like a nightmare now, to be able to redo all this logic.

Can you please share your thougths on how to do in a better way? I'm new to Django, so looks like I'm doing something wrong here

Here is how my main view inside views.py looks like:

```
class ResultsView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
model = Ads
paginate_by = 9
template_name = 'library.html'

#GET SEARCH
def get_queryset(self):
    query_search = self.request.GET.get('search')
    query_sort = self.request.GET.get('sort_by')
    query_filter = self.request.GET.get('filter_by_language')
    query_search_username = self.request.GET.get('search_username')

    #search=YES, sort=NO, filter=NO
    if query_search and not query_sort and not query_filter:
        object_list = self.model.objects.filter(Q(headline__icontains=query_search) or Q(promoted_url__icontains=query_search))
    
    elif query_search_username: #and not query_sort and not query_filter:
        object_list = self.model.objects.filter(Q(username__iexact=query_search_username))

    #search=YES, sort=NO, filter=YES
    elif query_search and not query_sort and query_filter:
        object_list = self.model.objects.filter(Q(headline__icontains=query_search) or Q(promoted_url__icontains=query_search))
        object_list = object_list.filter(language__iexact=query_filter)

    #search=YES, sort=YES, filter=NO
    elif query_search and query_sort and not query_filter:
        object_list = self.model.objects.filter(Q(headline__icontains=query_search) or Q(promoted_url__icontains=query_search)).order_by(query_sort)
    
    #search=YES, sort=YES, filter=NO
    elif query_search and query_sort and query_filter:
        object_list = self.model.objects.filter(Q(headline__icontains=query_search) or Q(promoted_url__icontains=query_search))
        object_list = object_list.filter(language__iexact=query_filter).order_by(query_sort)

    #search=NO, sort=YES, filter=NO
    elif not query_search and query_sort and not query_filter:
        object_list = self.model.objects.all().order_by(query_sort)

    #search=NO, sort=YES, filter=YES
    elif not query_search and query_sort and query_filter:
        object_list = self.model.objects.filter(language__iexact=query_filter).order_by(query_sort)

    #search=NO, sort=NO, filter=YES
    elif not query_search and not query_sort and query_filter:
        object_list = self.model.objects.filter(language__iexact=query_filter)

    #ELSE
    else:
        object_list = self.model.objects.order_by('?')
    return object_list
```

Comment: About the languages: Only Latin or do you have some characters outside of the UTF8?

Comment: @Blind2k only latin (this is just a list of values such as "English", "German", etc.

Comment: Alright.
Can you post the models?.
You might be able to use eager-loading but I need to see the models to be sure.